# python script to Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

i have python script named a.py
inside that script i have a function named fun that check all the number from 0 to 99 and return True if the integer is even and False if the integer is odd.

```
def fun():
     for i in range(100) :
          if i % 2 == 0 :
               return True
          else :
               return False
```

i want to run this script in Robot Framework

```
*** Settings ***
Library     a.py


*** Test Cases ***
Test
    ${val} =    a.fun 
    Should Be Equal     ${val}  ${True}
```

i can't run all the test cases i have just the result of the first iteration.
i want run all the test cases.
I know that  i can use Robot Framework directly but i dont want to use the Robot Framework syntax.

Comment: This is *EXACTLY* the same issue as with your previous question. You have a loop in python but return will exit that loop and only first value from range() is checked ..

Comment: i give this example instead of the other one to clarify the situation

Comment: And  my first answer to the original question was about this *exact* thing that this once again reproduces.. Let me give you a full answer in actual comment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have has nothing to do with Robot Framework but your python code just doesnt work as you expected - as i tried to explain in the original code. Here's 100% python code that should visualize your issue and take my original answer into account:

```py
def fun():
    for i in range(100):
        print(f"verify ${i=}")
        if i % 2 == 0:
            print(f"Before return of {i=} is even")
            return True
            print(f"After return of {i=} is even")
        else:
            print(f"Before return of {i=} is odd")
            return False
            print(f"After return of {i=} is odd")

    print("This will never be printed because for look will 100% exit before code reaches here")

def even_more_fun():
    results = []
    for i in range(100):
        print(f"verify ${i=}")
        if i % 2 == 0:
            print(f"Before return of {i=} is even")
            results.append(True)
            print(f"After return of {i=} is even")
        else:
            print(f"Before return of {i=} is odd")
            results.append(False)
            print(f"After return of {i=} is odd")
    print("This will be printed because we went thru the whole loop but now, results for each value in your given range..")
    return results


print("Calling fun() - see the output of your code")
result_of_fun = fun()
print("Calling even_more_fun() - see the output even more closely")
result_of_even_more_fun = even_more_fun()

print("And now we print the results")
print(f"{result_of_fun=}")
print(f"{result_of_even_more_fun=}")
```

Now, `fun()` gets called once..  It will return a single *True* value because `0 % 2 == 0` evaluates to True. Then your code will stop execution because you have a return state to return that value.

Next, `even_more_fun()` - it also gets called once but it will return a list of results for every item in your test data, which is `range(100)` in your case.

Copy that script to your machine and run it .. See the difference of outputs from fun() and even_more_fun().

This is how robot *and* python handles it (and *any* other sane programming language).

You either have the list of all values you want to test **ON YOUR ROBOT CODE** and you call `fun()` separately with each value **OR** you fix your python code and return a list of results for each value to make your code work and then return that list.